# Jackson Serialize Subclasses

Tags: jackson

I need to serialize a 3rd superclass with more than 20 subclasses, which means i can't use Jackson annotations. So i need to write CustomSerializers.

Superclass:

```
class Poi {

    String name
    double lng
    double lat
}
```

One of many Subclasses:

```
class Parkingspace extends Poi {

    int freeParkingSpaces
}
```

Currently i got 2 Options in my mind.

1. writing a SuperClassSerializer:

```
class PoiSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Poi> {
    @Override
    void serialize(Poi value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject()
            gen.writeStringField("name", value.name)
            gen.writeNumberField("lng", value.lng)
            gen.writeNumberField("lat", value.lat)
            
            if (value instanceof Parkingspace) {
                gen.writeNumberField("freeParkingSpaces", value.freeParkingSpaces)
            }
            //add other if-conditions for subclasses here
            ...
           
        gen.writeEndObject()
    }
}
```

2. writing a Serializer for EVERY Subclass

```
class ParkingSpaceSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ParkingSpace> {
    @Override
    void serialize(ParkingSpace value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject()
            gen.writeStringField("name", value.name)
            gen.writeNumberField("lng", value.lng)
            gen.writeNumberField("lat", value.lat)
            gen.writeNumberField("freeParkingSpaces", value.freeParkingSpaces)           
        gen.writeEndObject()
    }
}
```

The serializations with approach 1 slows down the more if conditions for subclasses i have to implement. Approach 2 produces very much boilerplate code, because if have many Serializers, always with the Superclass properties. What approach is the better one?
Or is there a jackson way of Serializer inheritance (couldn't find anything in jackson docu)?